# Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html in IIS7.5

Tags: html, asp.net, iis-7.5

I have a web application that I'm trying to install in my local IIS. I'm using IIS 7.5. The problem I'm having is that my application comes up but my css styles gives me `Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html` error. This only happens while I'm not authenticated in the application. So I tried different options for this error.

1. Verified my MIME type on the application. The .css type is set to type/CSS.
2. Verified all my permissions for the folder in the Security Tab. Assigned to IIS_IUSRS and for NETWORK SERVICE groups Full Control to the Root folder. (Even tried adding Everyone to share with Read/Write access)
3. The only thing that "worked" was adding the specific CSS folder to my web.config. The problem with this approach is that I didn't needed to do this before for this application. So there should be something that is causing this problem.

`<location path="css">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="?" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>`

4. Also tried adding the .htaccess file (even though this is not Apache). To see if this worked and not.
5. Verified the Static Content that is checked in the Add Features section.

I'm running out of options for this one. If anyone know anything else that should be consider, will be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Guess: the return type `html` - is it because it's an error page (404 etc.)? It might help you nail the (actual) issue (maybe it's just a path, though it sounds like `unauthorized` rather than MIME). You can use browser dev tools and inspect the actual request for the css resource and see what response the browser got, or simply browse to it (anonymously). Hth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem once and I was able to solve it by re-installing the IIS

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! Don't know why but after re-installing the IIS now my application runs as expected.